# How does encapsulation work in C# Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
protected override IEnumerator InitUI()
{
 //some code here
   { //---> is this encapsulation or a class inside of a function?
      //some code here
   }
}
```

My question is on the comment line of the code:

I'm not sure if it is or not. Would someone help me understand and please explain. I'm just a beginner on C#.

## EDIT:

Here is the whole code:

```
 protected override IEnumerator InitUI()
{
    // 3DS UI . 
    Transform tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 0)");
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/minimap_type_b (x_ 1575, 1356)", tf));
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/replay", tf));

    tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 1~2)");
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/logo", tf));
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/card_open_window", tf));
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/ranking", tf));
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/top_bar", tf));

    tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 10~11)");
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/midterm_loading", tf));

    tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 12)");
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/Screen3DUI/game_result", tf));

    loading.SetValue(0.02f);    // 2%.

    //3DS UI
    {
        Screen3DUI screen_3d = gameObject.AddComponent<Screen3DUI>();
        MiniMapUI_TypeB minimap = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 0)/minimap_type_b (x_ 1575, 1356)").GetComponent<MiniMapUI_TypeB>();
        ReplayUI replay = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 0)/replay").GetComponent<ReplayUI>();
        InGameLogo logo = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 1~2)/logo").GetComponent<InGameLogo>();
        BetBoardCardOpenWindow card_open_window = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 1~2)/card_open_window").GetComponent<PC_CardBoard>();
        RankingUI ranking = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 1~2)/ranking").GetComponent<RankingUI>();
        BetBoardTopBar topbar = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 1~2)/top_bar").GetComponent<BetBoardTopBar>();
        MidtermLoading mid_loading = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 10~11)/midterm_loading").GetComponent<MidtermLoading>();
        ResultUI result = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/Screen3DUI/panel (depth 12)/game_result").GetComponent<CC_US_ResultWindow>();

        //[PK CODE 1/18/2018]
        MC_HorseRacingType racing_type = gameObject.AddComponent<MC_HorseRacingType>();

        screen_3d.InjectObject(logo, replay, minimap, card_open_window, ranking, topbar, mid_loading, result);

        yield return StartCoroutine(minimap.Init());
        yield return StartCoroutine(replay.Init());
        yield return StartCoroutine(logo.Init());
        yield return StartCoroutine(card_open_window.Init());
        yield return StartCoroutine(ranking.Init());
        yield return StartCoroutine(topbar.Init());
        yield return StartCoroutine(result.Init());

        loading.SetValue(0.03f); // 3%
    }


    tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/UserConsoleUI/panel (depth 4~5)");
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/UserConsoleUI/bet_board", tf));
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/UserConsoleUI/bottom_bar", tf));

    tf = transform.Find("UI Root/FullscreenPanel/UserConsoleUI/panel (depth 8~9)");
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/UserConsoleUI/dealer_cam", tf));
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/UserConsoleUI/bet_message", tf));
    yield return StartCoroutine(LoadAsync("MC_VERSION/{0}/UI/UserConsoleUI/round_message", tf));

    loading.SetValue(0.04f);    // 4%.
}
```

Comment: How do you understand encapsulation ?

Comment: Unclear/too broad... Explaining broad concepts like "encapsulation" is generally off-topic on SO. You may want to start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming) if you are really looking for that word.

Comment: @Nexus by having { } something like that sir.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm sorry sir but i couldn't find the same format as that on google . Sorry for asking too broad question.

Comment: you might as well include the code before the `{}`

Comment: @GeomanYabes edited my code sir

Comment: that would be a *block* of code, in which you can define variables, that would not be accessible outside the block. I can see how you could call that *encapsulation*, but that would not the context/way of using *encapsulation* I am used to.

Comment: But anyway, that would *not* be another class.

Comment: @NoobProgrammer that is not the idea of 'encapsulation' at all. It just a nested block of code as Pac0 mentioned . The {code ins side}  can work with or without the parenthesis .

Comment: Ow i see now i understand . Thank you very much guys. Thank you for explaining sir @Pac0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a block of code `{}` inside a function would just be that, a nested block of code.

The use of this could be to properly separate some lines of code. In that block, all variables defined would not be visible outside the block.

> is this encapsulation or a class inside of a function?

It's definitely not another class.

I can *understand* why you want to call it *encapsulation*, but that would not be the word used in this case. *Encapsulation* in Object Oriented Programming is much stronger than just hiding some variables in a block of code.

As a personal preference, I would tend to create a whole new private function for that, at least that would give this block of code a meaningful name.

(but any variable used from outside the block inside would have to be passed as parameter)

```
void yourFunction() 
{
    // some code
    {
       // some inner code
    }
}
```

I would write this instead :

```
void yourFunction() 
{
    // some code

    innerFunction();
}

void innerFunction()
{
    // some inner code
}
```

For clarification, the below code is an example of what most professional programmers mean by the term "enacpsulation". In this, your variables are protected by what are known as "getters" and "setters".

```
public class RPGCharacter
{
   private int health;
   public int Health
   {
       get { return health; }
       set {
             health = value;
             if(health <= 0) 
             {
                 health = 0; // force zero as min value
                 this.Die();
             }
       }
   }
   void Die() {
       Debug.Log("No more health, you died !");
   }

}
```

In this example I have successfully Encapsulated my private "health" value, and in doing so I have protected the RPGCharacter from ever having a health below 0, since that would not make sense.

Comment: While this is a great answer, I would recommend a small example of getters and setters for future readers to visualize the difference.

Comment: @BrandonMiller do you mean getters and setters in *another class* to show encapsulation of variables / logic ?

Comment: btw, don't hesitate to submit edit on my question if you feel something would fit in nicely)

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I mean. For people like me, I always learned better by visually looking at code and I think it would help clarify the difference to people like myself.

Answer (score 2):

To make it clear, this question has nothing to do with the coding issue, but rather than an explanation of a concept.

"Encapsulation" is that you'll have to 'package' and 'protect' all your essential variables/ methods within a Class. Hence , most of the time , you will use `private` property to make them inaccessible.

```
protected class InitUI()
{
  private int a,b,c;

  private sum()
  {
    c = a + b;
  }

}
```

Then we say InitUI is encapsulated . To answer your question:

```
 protected override IEnumerator InitUI()
{
 //some code here
   { //---> is this encapsulation or a class inside of a function?
      //some code here
   }
}
```

It is not a class, not a function and not an encapsulation. Just a simple block of code and it can work with or without the parenthesis `{ //some code here }`